Issue with Editing Email Template in Salesforce Marketing Cloud (Lock Icon)
I'm encountering an issue with editing email templates in Salesforce Marketing Cloud. There’s a lock icon in the top-left corner of the template, which prevents me from making any changes directly to the template.
Strangely, when I add a new block to the email, it seems to get added to the template. Currently, I want to add custom CSS to the  section, but I can't. ESPs don't support inline media queries, so I have no way of adding this.
Is there a way to create emails using a template that allows full editing, like adding CSS to the ? The only solution I can see right now is creating the email in full HTML without a template, which allows me to edit the entire code in "Code View."
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Based on what you described, it seems you were trying to edit an email (Template-Based Email) while you needed to edit the email template (Template).
A Template-Based Email is an email that you already have a template for this one.
To find the using template, just need to switch to the "Properties" tab when you edit that email, it is supposed to show you the template name, from there you can find the template and edit it (e.g. add media queries).
When finished editing the template, the final step is to go back to the Properties tab in the email and click "Update Email Now".
